# How to do Sliding Window Rank in Spark using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window, apache-spark-mllib, ranking-functions

I have a data set :

```
+-----+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+
|query|similar_queries    |model_score          |count             |
+-----+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+
|shirt|funny shirt        |0.0034038130658784866|189.0             |
|shirt|shirt womens       |0.0019435265241921438|136.0             |
|shirt|watch              |0.001097496453284101 |212.0             |
|shirt|necklace           |6.694577024597908E-4 |151.0             |
|shirt|white shirt        |0.0037413097560623485|217.0             |
|shirt|shoes              |0.0022062579255572733|575.0             |
|shirt|crop top           |9.065831060804897E-4 |173.0             |
|shirt|polo shirts for men|0.007706416273211698 |349.0             |
|shirt|shorts             |0.002669621942466027 |200.0             |
|shirt|black shirt        |0.03264296242546658  |114.0             |
+-----+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

I am ranking the data set based on "count" first.

```
lazy val countWindowByFreq = Window.partitionBy(col(QUERY)).orderBy(col(COUNT).desc)
val ranked_data = data.withColumn("count_rank", row_number over countWindowByFreq)

+-----+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+----------+
|query|similar_queries    |model_score          |count             |count_rank|
+-----+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+----------+
|shirt|shoes              |0.0022062579255572733|575.0             |1         |
|shirt|polo shirts for men|0.007706416273211698 |349.0             |2         |
|shirt|white shirt        |0.0037413097560623485|217.0             |3         |
|shirt|watch              |0.001097496453284101 |212.0             |4         |
|shirt|shorts             |0.002669621942466027 |200.0             |5         |
|shirt|funny shirt        |0.0034038130658784866|189.0             |6         |
|shirt|crop top           |9.065831060804897E-4 |173.0             |7         |
|shirt|necklace           |6.694577024597908E-4 |151.0             |8         |
|shirt|shirt womens       |0.0019435265241921438|136.0             |9         |
|shirt|black shirt        |0.03264296242546658  |114.0             |10        |
+-----+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+----------+
```

I am now trying to rank the content using a rolling window on row_number(4 rows) and rank within the window based on model_score. For e.g.:

In the first window, row_number 1 to 4, the new rank(new column) will be

```
1. polo shirts for men
2. white shirt
3. shoes
4. watch
```

In the first window, row_number 5 to 8, the new rank(new column) will be

```
5. funny shirt
6. shorts
7. shirt womens 
8. crop top
```

In the first window, row_number 9 to rest, the new rank(new column) will be

```
9. black shirt 
10. shirt womens
```

Can some one tell me if there how can I achieve with this spark and Scala ? Is there any pre-defined functions I can use ?

I tried :

lazy val MODEL_RANK = Window.partitionBy(col(QUERY))
    .orderBy(col(MODEL_SCORE).desc).rowsBetween( 0, 3)

but this gives me :

```
sql.AnalysisException: Window Frame ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3 FOLLOWING must match the required frame ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW;
```

Also, tried with .rowsBetween(-3, 0) but that also gives me error :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window Frame ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW must match the required frame ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW;
```

Comment: What is the expected output data frame?

Comment: @ollik1 The expected o/p is 1. polo shirts for men
2. white shirt
3. shoes
4. watch 5. funny shirt
6. shorts
7. shirt womens 
8. crop top 9. black shirt 
10. shirt womens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `count_rank` computed, next step is to find a way to group the row in a set of fours. It can be done as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val ranked_data_grouped = ranked_data
  .withColumn("bucket", (($"count_rank" -1)/4).cast(IntegerType))
```

ranked_data_grouped will look like:

```
+-----+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+----------+-------+
|query|similar_queries    |model_score          |count             |count_rank|bucket |
+-----+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+----------+-------+
|shirt|shoes              |0.0022062579255572733|575.0             |1         |0      |
|shirt|polo shirts for men|0.007706416273211698 |349.0             |2         |0      |      
|shirt|white shirt        |0.0037413097560623485|217.0             |3         |0      |
|shirt|watch              |0.001097496453284101 |212.0             |4         |0      |
|shirt|shorts             |0.002669621942466027 |200.0             |5         |1      |
|shirt|funny shirt        |0.0034038130658784866|189.0             |6         |1      |
|shirt|crop top           |9.065831060804897E-4 |173.0             |7         |1      |
|shirt|necklace           |6.694577024597908E-4 |151.0             |8         |1      |
|shirt|shirt womens       |0.0019435265241921438|136.0             |9         |2      |
|shirt|black shirt        |0.03264296242546658  |114.0             |10        |2      |
+-----+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+----------+-------+
```

Now, all you have to do is, partition by `bucket` & order by `model_score`:

```
val output = ranked_data_grouped
  .withColumn("finalRank", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"bucket").orderBy($"model_score".desc)))
```

Comment: But this doesn't give finalRank from 1 to n.. it gives me 1..4 again 1..4 and so on.. Is there a way to get final rank 1.. n ie.. 1..4 (group 0) followed 5..8 (rank 1 to 4 of group1)..

Comment: I got it- val output = ranked_data_grouped
  .withColumn("finalRanksTemp", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"bucket").orderBy(col("model_score").desc)))
    .withColumn("finalRanks", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"query").orderBy(col("bucket"), col("finalRanksTemp"))))